# Is my Nginx proxy serving as a middleman or simply redirecting my users to the upstream server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx proxy server pointed to an internal server with the proxy_pass directive.

When I attempt to use the proxy from within the network, everything is fine, but connecting to the proxy from outside the network, I get the upstream server, but clicking a link gives a *browser* timeout message. (In Chrome, [Internal IP] is taking too long to respond)

This doesn't make any sense to me. Is Nginx telling my browser to redirect to this internal IP? It should be sending the request for the clicked link to the upstream server and forwarding the response down to the client, not resetting the connection.

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know how you configured things. Could you please edit the question and include your nginx config?

Comment: Config please.  It's a proxy not a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is a middleman, if you are using proxy_pass. However, it sounds like it might not be rewriting the replies from your internal web server correctly. So, maybe you might be missing this second line in your configuration?

```
  proxy_pass http://internal-server/;
  proxy_redirect http://internal-server/ http://$server_name/;
```

Replace internal-server with the internal hostname or ip address of your server. $server_name is a variable that uses whatever you configured server_name to be. It will likely work as is.

If you have any more configuration questions, please ask.

Another possibility from your description is that your upstream web server might be configured to use it's own internal hostname or ip address instead of the external assigned hostname in the content of the body. The redirect line above will only change the http header info in the reply from your web server, it will not change content in the webpage of the reply from your server. So you will need to be careful about the links your web server is issuing in the body of your web pages. Some web content systems do a better job of handling these issues than others, so telling us what you are using for your web server will help us understand how to help you. Wordpress, for example has a simple setting for the url used to access the server. Other systems may or may not be more complicated.

I'm assuming you use exactly the same url when inside and outside the network?

In either case, your webserver itself would be causing you to bypass the reverse proxy server when you are inside your network where you would have direct access to the internal server. You obviously do not have that direct access when outside.